# Minimizing .NET code or make it more efficient

Tags: c#, .net, razor-pages

I'm developing an overview of an electronic locker system for products with 5 slots.
What I want to achive is to automaticly populate each "locker slot"'s dropdown and select the correct product in each slot.

There can also be mulitple lockers, so I dont know the best and the moste effectiv way to achive this.

Index.cshtml

```
    @foreach (var locker in Model.Lockers)
                {
                    <div class="lockBox slot1 unavailible">
                            <div>
                                <select asp-items="Model.OptionSlot1">
                                    <option value="">– Empty slot –</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            1
                     </div>
<div class="lockBox slot2 unavailible">
                            <div>
                                <select asp-items="Model.OptionSlot2">
                                    <option value="">– Empty slot –</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            2
                     </div>
<div class="lockBox slot3 unavailible">
                            <div>
                                <select asp-items="Model.OptionSlot3">
                                    <option value="">– Empty slot –</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            3
                     </div>
<div class="lockBox slot4 unavailible">
                            <div>
                                <select asp-items="Model.OptionSlot4">
                                    <option value="">– Empty slot –</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            4
                     </div>
<div class="lockBox slot5 unavailible">
                            <div>
                                <select asp-items="Model.OptionSlot5">
                                    <option value="">– Empty slot –</option>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            5
                     </div>
                }
```

Index.cshtml.cs

```
    var userId = User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
            Lockers = await LockerManager.GetLockers(userId);
            Products = await ProductManger.GetProducts(userId);
            Box = await BoxManager.GetBoxes(userId);

            var box1 = Box.Where(a => a.BoxNo == 1).ToList()[0];
            var prod1 = Products.Where(p => p.Id == box1.ProductId).ToList()[0];
            OptionsSlot1 = Products.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name,
                Selected = box1.ProductId == prod1.Id ? true : false
            }).ToList();

var box1 = Box.Where(a => a.BoxNo == 1).ToList()[0];
            var prod1 = Products.Where(p => p.Id == box1.ProductId).ToList()[0];
            OptionsSlot1 = Products.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name,
                Selected = box1.ProductId == prod1.Id ? true : false
            }).ToList();

var box2 = Box.Where(a => a.BoxNo == 2).ToList()[0];
            var prod2 = Products.Where(p => p.Id == box2.ProductId).ToList()[0];
            OptionsSlot2 = Products.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name,
                Selected = box2.ProductId == prod2.Id ? true : false
            }).ToList();

var box3 = Box.Where(a => a.BoxNo == 3).ToList()[0];
            var prod3 = Products.Where(p => p.Id == box3.ProductId).ToList()[0];
            OptionsSlot3 = Products.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name,
                Selected = box3.ProductId == prod3.Id ? true : false
            }).ToList();

var box4 = Box.Where(a => a.BoxNo == 4).ToList()[0];
            var prod4 = Products.Where(p => p.Id == box4.ProductId).ToList()[0];
            OptionsSlot4 = Products.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name,
                Selected = box4.ProductId == prod4.Id ? true : false
            }).ToList();

var box5 = Box.Where(a => a.BoxNo == 5).ToList()[0];
            var prod5 = Products.Where(p => p.Id == box5.ProductId).ToList()[0];
            OptionsSlot5 = Products.Select(a => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = a.Id.ToString(),
                Text = a.Name,
                Selected = box5.ProductId == prod5.Id ? true : false
            }).ToList();
```

Comment: You ask to make it smaller or more efficient. Are you running into performance issues with this code? Or do you think it's too much code?

Comment: One thing you can do to reduce the amount of code is to remove all of the `? true : false`. It's like saying "if the value is true, the value is true, but if the value is false, the value is false" instead of just "the value is true" or "the value is false".

Comment: @WouterdeKort, no Im not runing into performance issues, however this wound be sustainable once there are lockers with 200 slots.

Comment: I would rather like to see a loop then to write code for every slot.

Comment: you could use a dictionary instead. and in the cshtml use a partial view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now been able to narrow it down to a single loop. If anyone else is intressted, here is code:

```
IList<int> boxes = new List<int> { 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 2, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30 };

                                foreach (var boxNo in boxes)
                                {
                                    var box = Model.Box.Where(a => a.BoxNo == boxNo && a.LockerId == locker.Id).ToList()[0];
                                    var status = (Model.Box.Where(x => x.BoxNo == boxNo && x.LockerId == locker.Id).ToList()[0].Status) == 1 ? "availible" : "unavailible";

                                    if (boxNo == 1 || boxNo == 2)
                                        status = "locked";

                                    <div class="box @status" id="box@(boxNo)">
                                        <div>
                                            <select name="@(locker.Id + "_" + @boxNo)" id="@(locker.Id + "_" + @boxNo)">
                                                <option value="0">–</option>
                                                @foreach (var product in Model.Products)
                                                {
                                                    <option value="@product.Id" selected="@(box.ProductId == product.Id)">@product.Name</option>
                                                }
                                            </select>
                                        </div>
                                        @boxNo
                                    </div>
                                }
```